# how to use psyaprk's dataframe to get a withColumn?

Tags: python, timestamp, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

I want to gt like `2017-03-01 02:00:00` to change `2017-03-01`, but the first picture is `2021=2017+3+1`, the second picture is `null`

Comment: what's the datatype of T_Start column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution to get what you want :

```
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    df = df.withColumn("day", F.udf(lambda x : x.split(" ")[0])(F.col("T_START"))
```

And if you want to transform your column to datetype you could cast it as :

```
    import pyspark.sql.types as T
    df = df.withColumn("day", col("day").cast(T.DateType()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `to_date` to convert a TimeStamp to a Date.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df1.withColumn("day", psf.to_date("T_START"))
```

Concatenation doesn't work with `+` in pyspark you have to use function `concat` that operates on columns (`'-'` should be in a `lit`). Or `concat_ws` that works like a python `join`, concatenating strings with a same separator.

`month` and `dayofmonth` will return integers, you won't have te trailing 0's.

Comment: No problem messi :) don't forget to mark your question as solved